# Is every probability measure in the line induced by a random variable?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

It is a basic fact in probability theory that, for every random variable
$$
X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}),
$$
we have an associated measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ on the borelians of $\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
\mathbb{P}_X(B) := \mathbb{P}(X \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)), \forall B \in \mathbb{B}.   
$$
$\mathbb{P}_X$ is called the **measure induced by $X$**.

My question: is the opposite also true? That is, given a probability measure on the borelians of $\mathbb{R}$, is it induced by a random variable? More precisely:

Is there a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that, given a probability measure $\mu$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, one can find a random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ such that $\mu$ is induced by $X$?

I aprreciate your concern!

[Edit]

What I really want is a probability space that can be used for global representation of probability measures as measures induced by random variables. I have a guess that the space $\Omega = \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | f \:\text{is Borel measurable}\}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra of cilinders and some appropriate measure is the space desired, but I'm not pretty sure on how to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P) = ([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]),\mathcal L)$ where $\mathcal L$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Fix your measure $\mu$, and write $F(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])$.

Let $X(\omega)= \inf\{z : F(z) \ge \omega \}$. This is known as the *Skorokhod Representation* of the random variable $X$.

I'll leave you to verify that the distribution of $X$ is exactly given by $F$. (However, if this gives you trouble, see section 3.12 of the reference below.)

Reference:

Williams, D. (1991). *Probability with martingales*. Cambridge university press.

Comment: I guess we had the same idea.  But I always thought "Skorokhod representation" usually referred to representing $\mu$ by a random variable of the form $B_\tau$, where $B_t$ is Brownian motion and $\tau$ is a stopping time.  (There is also the so-called "Skorokhod representation theorem" where you convert a sequence converging in distribution to a sequence converging almost surely.)

Comment: @Nate Yes, it doesn't appear to be the commonly used term for this. (For example, a Google query for "Skorkohod representation" doesn't seem to be consistent with my post.) However, it is what Williams calls it, so I defer to them.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  This is the trick that you use to prove the "Skorokhod representation theorem" I mentioned above.  You just do it for a whole sequence of random variables instead of just one.

Comment: @Nate Huh, good point. That's nice to know. Always nice to unify concepts in my head with the same name but ostensibly refer to different things. Though, I am also used to calling the first idea in your first comment the "Skorokhod embedding problem".

Answer (score 8):

Yes, trivially: consider the probability space $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}$, $\mathbb{P} = \mu$, and let $X : \Omega = \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the identity map $X(\omega) = \omega$.

Alternatively, use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  Let $F(x) = \mu((-\infty, x])$ be the cumulative distribution function of $\mu$, and let $G(t) = \inf\{x : F(x) \ge t\}$ be its "inverse".  (If $F$ is actually 1-1 then $G$ is truly the inverse of $F$.)  Now let $U$ be a Uniform(0,1) random variable on any probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ (e.g. the identity map on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure) and set $X = G(U)$. It is then easy to see that the measure induced by $X$ is again $\mu$.  Proof: we have $\mathbb{P}(X \le x) = \mathbb{P}(G(U) \le x) = \mathbb{P}(U \le F(x)) = F(x)$.  So the measure induced by $X$ has $F$ as its cdf, and this uniquely determines it as being $\mu$.

Comment: Thank youj very much. Notice that the first par of your answer is not quite what i was looking for, for i want a fixed probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where i can define all the random variables $X$ which will eventually represent the different probability measures of $\mathbb{R}$. But the second part gives it, and a i aprreciate!

Comment: @Brisão: You're welcome.  More generally, if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is any uncountable standard Borel space and $\mathbb{P}$ is atomless, then every probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (or indeed on any standard Borel space $\Omega'$) is induced by some random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (respectively, $X : \Omega \to \Omega'$).  So any such probability space is "universal" in the sense that you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Can this be expanded to more general $ \Omega' $? A paper I'm trying to understand uses this for $ \Omega' $ as the space of non-negative finite measures on $ \mathbb R$.  It simply reads, denote by $X$ a random variable taking values in the space of non-negative finite measures on $ \mathbb R$ that is distributed according to some given probability measure.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: You can just apply the trivial version there.  If $M$ is the space of nonnegative finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mu$ is a probability measure on some appropriate $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ on $M$, then trivially the identity map $X = id$ can be viewed as a measurable function from the probability space $(M, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ to the measurable space $(M,\mathcal{B})$, so it is an $M$-valued random variable whose induced probability measure (aka the distribution or law of $X$) is trivially seen to be $\mu$.  This works on any measurable space.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: There might be a question of what to take for the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, if not specified, but if I recall correctly the weak topology and the total variation topology on $M$ both induce the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra, so presumably that's what is meant for $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: Often the reason for introducing such a random variable is as much for notational convenience as anything else.  It may be sort of a toss-up whether you prefer to write $\mathbb{P}(X \in A)$ versus $\mu(A)$, but for instance, something like $\mathbb{P}(3X+7 \in A)$ is more readable than "let $f(x) = 3x+7$ and consider $\mu(f^{-1}(A))$."

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have mentioned, we are considering the weak topology on $M$. Sadly, I don't think I can apply the trivial version here as I don't get to choose the probability measure. The situation is as follows:

Comment: We start with some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and define a sequence $\xi_n$ of random variables with values in the measure space $M$. For each $\xi_n$ we have an induced probability measure $P_n$ on $M$. Via a tightness argument, we can then show, that these $P_n$ (or rather a subsequence) converge weakly to some probability measure $P^*$ on M. Then the paper goes on to say, we simply denote by $\xi$ a random variable on $M$ distributed according to $P^*$.

Comment: The problem in choosing $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ to be $M$ with the weak topology and $P^*$ is that $P^*$ depends on the initial $P$. Maybe there is an argument, that if our $P_n$ are induced by random variables $\xi_n$ and converge weakly, then the limit is also induced by a random variable $\xi$ but I don't see it.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: If you look carefully at the argument, I expect you will find there is no need for $\xi$ to be defined on the same probability space as the $\xi_n$, since there doesn't seem to be any use made of a joint distribution between the $\xi_n$ and $\xi$.  For instance, weak convergence of random variables makes perfect sense even if they are defined on different probability spaces.  So you could define $\xi$ trivially on the probability space $(M, \mathcal{B}, P^*)$ instead.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: Alternatively, "enhance" $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ by replacing it with the product space $(\Omega \times M, \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}, P \otimes P^*)$.  Then the $\xi_n$ make sense as functions of the first coordinate, and you can define $\xi$ trivially as the identity function of the second coordinate.  This makes $\xi$ independent of the $\xi_n$, which is fine since the joint distribution should be irrelevant.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: Or third, if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is standard Borel (probably a safe assumption to add), then it can support a random variable in any standard Borel space with any distribution.  The weak topology on $M$ is Polish, I believe, so $(M, \mathcal{B})$ is standard Borel, and then there does exist a $\xi : \Omega \to M$ with distribution $P^*$.  Here the existence of $\xi$ is kind of abstract, and you can't say anything about its joint distribution with the $\xi_n$, but again we should not need to.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Nate! I actually do need the $\xi_n$ and $\xi$ to be defined on the same probability space because of some other variables defined on this initial probability space. But it's still interesting to note, that for the notion of weak convergence, we don't need the variables to be defined on the same space. However your second suggestion, replacing the space with the product space, works nicely. You're right, the joint distribution of the variables does not matter. Thanks for this simple solution! Do you happen to have a reference for the statement in your last comment?

Comment: @FlorianEnte: I left out an assumption: $P$ must be atomless.  Assuming this, let $E$ be any standard Borel space, and $\mu$ any probability measure on $E$.  Recall the fact that any two standard Borel spaces are Borel isomorphic.  Lemma 1: there exists an $\mathbb{R}$-valued uniform(0,1) random variable on $\Omega$.  Proof: let $\phi : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel isomorphism; we can also view it as an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable $X$, whose distribution is continuous since $P$ is atomless.  Let $F_X$ be its cdf. Let $U := F_X(X)$ and verify $U \sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: Lemma 2: given $U$, there is a measurable map $\sigma : \mathbb{R} \to E$ such that $\sigma(U) \sim \mu$.  Proof: let $\psi : E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel isomorphism.  Consider the pushforward measure $\mu' = \mu \circ \psi^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $G$ be its cdf (not necessarily 1-1).  Following [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), let $G^{-1}$ be the generalized inverse of $G$.  Then $G^{-1}(U) \sim \mu'$, and so $\psi^{-1}(G^{-1}(U)) \sim \mu$.  Thus $\sigma := \psi^{-1} \circ G^{-1}$ is as desired.

Comment: @FlorianEnte: But I don't offhand know where it is written down in one place.